# Rails 6.1 using Image Magick causing Backing store not supported error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick

We recently upgraded to Rails 6.1 but we are still using ImageMagick which is where I believe the error is coming from.

We get a request like this:

```
https://www.website.com/rails/active_storage/representations/redirect/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBCQ1RqSmdFPSIsImV4cCI6bnVsbCwicHVyIjoiYmxvYl9pZCJ9fQ==--43c2a5d8d1363733f659494d48120fc50074a119/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaDdCam9MWm05eWJXRjBTU0lJYW5CbkJqb0dSVlE9IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJ2YXJpYXRpb24ifX0=--7e361caddd04f39dc6c9053ae311a33ecfe921ae/Music%20Magazine%20_NewLogo.jpg
```

Which causes this error:

```
A MiniMagick::Error occurred in redirect#show:

magick convert /tmp/ActiveStorage-19325732-20210812-14-1fe3obw.jpg[0] -auto-orient /tmp/image_processing20210812-14-1p16mlv.jpg` failed with error:
convert: Backing store not supported `/tmp/ActiveStorage-19325732-20210812-14-1fe3obw.jpg' @ error/jpeg.c/JPEGErrorHandler/346.
convert: no images defined `/tmp/image_processing20210812-14-1p16mlv.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3322.
```

I believe this is in the rails active storage redirect controller and no specific code that we are doing ourselves. How can I fix the issue? Is is an ImageMagick config issue?

Update: I think this has something to do with the size of the file. I was able to download this file, resize it, then reupload and now it works.

Comment: This does appear to involve some legacy code in `libjpeg` that isn't supported anymore and bombs out on large images (on some platforms anyway). What OS are you using?

Comment: We are using linux and have libjpeg-turbo v2.1.0 installed right now.